# How can I *unlock* a CoreStorage logical-volume without mounting it?

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, mount, repair, core-storage

I had a damaged disk that's encrypted with CoreStorage / FileVault. DiskWarrior was unable to operate on it while encrypted, obviously (“This is an offline, unavailable Core Storage disk.”); but the `diskutil corestorage unlockVolume [UUID]` operation *both* unlocks *and* mounts the volume.

With a damaged disk like this, I'd really like to avoid *mounting* the filesystem before working on it — I'd *just* like to unlock it so I can proceed with recovery tools.

Is there any way to enter the disk's password without causing it to subsequently be mounted by OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diskutil corestorage unlockVolume` has a `-nomount` option that you can use to achieve this exact effect.

Answer (score 2):

Click the Unlock button in the top-right of DiskWarrior and enter the password to unlock the volume

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We prefer answers be more than just 1 sentence, see [answer] for tips.  Also, how does this answer apply to what the OP stated about not wanting to enter the disk's password?

Comment: That worked for me. Unbelievable how its not clearer that you need to do that, but I didn't realize that the unlock was related to this problem until I saw Greg's answer